# MySQL: How to query high/low values for each day in a given period

Tags: mysql

Looking for a way to query a set amount of days and pull out the high and low value for each day in that period.

Table below has 4 days.

```
      t_stamp             value   
 2018-06-01 00:00:00      15.65
 2018-06-01 06:00:00      16.45
 2018-06-01 12:00:00      17.43
 2018-06-01 18:00:00      18.10
 2018-06-02 00:00:00      21.23
 2018-06-02 06:00:00      16.42
 2018-06-02 12:00:00      14.10
 2018-06-02 18:00:00      15.48
 2018-06-03 00:00:00      18.22
 2018-06-03 06:00:00      23.36
 2018-06-03 12:00:00      20.43
 2018-06-03 18:00:00      17.63
 2018-06-04 00:00:00      15.35
 2018-06-04 06:00:00      14.12
```

What query would I use to generate the follow for the 6/1 through 6/3?

```
    Date          Low     High
 2018-06-01      15.65    18.10             
 2018-06-02      14.10    21.23           
 2018-06-03      17.63    23.36
```

Generating it as a list with t_stamp and value will work too. I'll be able to work that out in the report program.

Comment: Hm. And what's the problem? `SELECT DATE(t_stamp), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)